# Why can't I create the JSON Object?

Tags: android, json, object, http-get

I'm using HTTP Get to retrieve a JSON formatted String from my website.

However, when I try to create the JSONObject, nothing happens. The object isn't created and I can't acces Arrays or anything inside it.

I've checked that my app does get the right String and it is correctly formatted as a JSON.

Do I have to declare it in some particular way or have separate try/catch blocks...?

I'm at my wits end with this, so any help would be most appreciated...

Lower you have all the code I've written in this issue and although it's not much, I'm stuck and don't know where to go with this...

```
public String result, testString;
public TextView resultText; 
public String url = "http://www.ace.ucv.ro/android/android.php";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

    resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    try {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        result = EntityUtils.toString(new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpGet).getEntity());

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
    resultText.setText(result);

}
```

Comment: you code looks right, how are you checking if the jsonObject is filled?

Comment: First of all no operation done after that with the JSONObject works, like getting arrays or values etc. Secondly, no instruction written in that try/catch block AFTER creating the Object is executed. (tested with something simple, like result = "test";

Comment: It looks like you are printing the stack trace... could you share it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you have in code (http://www.ace.ucv.ro/android/android.php) does not return Json object, instead it is a JSONArray.

Just replace JSONObject with JSONArray and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it works. However I still need to extract and store these into an array for each "title", "description" and so on. Is there any chance of doing that or would be easier to change the .php script? (seeing that I can't use the "getJSONArray("title"); method anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the string stored in result is just a JSONObject, or is it a JSONArray?

I remember stumbling on a similar problem.

Comment: String result should only store the JSON data that I get from the respective URL... I appologise, I'm quite the noob and this is a bit out of my league, but I'm doing my best to learn.

Comment: What 'should happen' isn't necessarily the same as what 'is happening'. And it looks like Peter above is confirming my suspicion. And that's why it's great to have the many eyes of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, your code looks familiar / reasonable. But perhaps you should un-nest it and log the intermediate results - which would help you see which stage is going wrong. For example...

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
Log.v("test", "HTTP response = " + response);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
Log.v("test", "HTTP entity = " + entity);
String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
Log.v("test", "HTTP content = " + content);
JSONObject mJsonObj = new JSONObject(mContent);
```

Comment: I already know that everything works fine until getting to creating the JSONObject with the String result. The string is correctly aquired by the app and it's a valid JSON